# Multiple params in Vuex action not working

Tags: vuex

I am having trouble getting my action to register both values that I pass to it from the front end. I know that the action only expects two params so I need to pass it as an object or an array but I keep getting undefined when I log out the values.

My action:

```
toggleMarkImportant: ({commit, state}, {row_id, bool}) => {
        console.log('fireball', row_id, bool)
        // axios.post('http://localhost:5050/api/important', {row_id, bool}).then(res=>{
        //     axios.get('http://localhost:5050/api/get-table-data').then(res=>{
        //         commit('SET_TABLE_ROWS', {tableRows: res.data})
        //     })
        // })
    }
```

Where I call it and pass in values:

```
<td v-if="row.important" class='star-box'>
    <i class="fas fa-star" @click="toggleMarkImportant({row_id: row.row_id, bool: true})"></i> 
</td>
```

I am able to get just the id if that's all I pass in so I know that the data is there and is correct. PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: Does it work to declare the method like this?

`toggleMarkImportant: ({commit, state}, params)`
and then access them using
`params.row_id;`
`params.bool;`

Comment: You're using arrow syntax for the action itself. Does the problem resolve itself if you just make it a normal ES6 function? Also, worth taking a look at async and await instead of .then etc. It tends to flow a bit nicer whilst keeping asynchronicity and reduce nesting.